# Testing apex:selectList when implemented using Custom Labels

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VF page where I am appending labels/values to a dropdown input from Custom Labels, like this:

```
<apex:selectList label="{!$Label.Type}" value="{!lstInputs.typeValue}" multiselect="false" size="1">
   <apex:selectOption itemValue="{!$Label.Option1}" itemLabel="{!$Label.Label1}"/>
   <apex:selectOption itemValue="{!$Label.Option2}" itemLabel="{!$Label.Label2}"/>
</apex:selectList>
<apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.Submit}"  action="{!callImplementor}" reRender="refresh"/>
```

I am using a Wrapper class to access all variables from my VF page. In my actual controller, I am using a method that gets this wrapper record as a parameter and builds a HTTP request.

```
public pagereference callImplementor() {
  try {
        implementor(lstInputs);
  } catch (Exception ex){

  }
}
public HttpRequest implementor(InputWrapper inp) {
    String selectedValue = (inp.typeValue != null ? inp.typeValue : '');
    System.debug('selectedValue :' +selectedValue);
    <--some code -->
}
//Wrapper
public class InputWrapper {
   public string typeValue {get; set;}
   //Other variables. 
}
```

Test class:

```
public static String adjValue = 'Option1';
  //test method
  static testmethod void testForCalloutSuccess(){
    Pagereference testPage = Page.MyVFPage;
    test.setCurrentPageReference(testPage);
    testPage.getParameters().put('acctId', actId);

    Test.startTest();

    MyControllerClass ctrl = new MyControllerClass();
    MyControllerClass.InputWrapper lstInput = new MyControllerClass.InputWrapper();
    lstInput.typeValue = adjValue;

    ctrl.callImplementor();
    //ctrl.implementor(lstInput);
    Test.stopTest(); 
}
```

I am getting my `selectedValue` as `null` in my test class. If I declare a test wrapper record, and call the method `implementor(InputWrapper inp)` by passing this record, some other field values are getting `null` as some values are set from constructor. How can I set the test data for this `<apex:selectList>` dropdown field from VF page?

Comment: where are the custom settings - i see custom labels?

Comment: My bad, those are custom labels. Will update my post.

Comment: use [edit] and show the _relevant_ portions of your testmethod

Comment: @cropredy Updated with test method.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely here:

```
MyControllerClass ctrl = new MyControllerClass();
MyControllerClass.InputWrapper lstInput = new MyControllerClass.InputWrapper();
lstInput.typeValue = adjValue;
```

this should be:

```
MyControllerClass ctrl = new MyControllerClass();
ctrl.lstInput = new MyControllerClass.InputWrapper();
ctrl.lstInput.typeValue = adjValue;
```

That is, you may have some confusion between static variables in your controller that should be object variables.

Comment: Still the selectedValue is null. I can kinda see what's happening with my issue, but really hard to figure it out.

Comment: Can I use something like this?:
`testPage.getParameters().put('{!$Label.Option1}', 'Option 1');`. All I need is a way to pass values from VF page to controller class. That way, my wrapper record can hold that data and my test can process further.

Comment: your testmethod needs to simulate solely `value="{!lstInputs.typeValue}"` and `action="{!callImplementor}"`. Labels are a red herring.  Edit your OP and show where `lstInput` is defined

Comment: Actually I dont really need `lstInput` variable in my test class as am calling this method from ctrl: `callImplementor()`. I am getting all my other variables, as I am setting up in the ctrl itself. How to simulate those VF input variables that can blend right in my test context?

Comment: I think I figured it.I will post it as an answer. Thanks much for your help.

Comment: cool - glad you are up and running

Answer (score 0):

After diving deep, I was able to simulate test data. Thanks to @cropredy for making me think loud. Just to add to my actual test method from my post,

```
Test.startTest();

MyControllerClass ctrl = new MyControllerClass();
MyControllerClass.InputWrapper lstInput = new MyControllerClass.InputWrapper();
ctrl.lstInput.typeValue = adjValue; //This is the way I should append(simulate) the test data. 
ctrl.callImplementor();

Test.stopTest();
```